How do I get the Hot Network Questions list back on the Stack Overflow front page?
I recently noticed that on the https://stackoverflow.com/ homepage, the hot network questions list was removed and it's basically completely destroyed my engagement with the site. I'm undecided whether that's a good or bad thing (At the very least it's removed some distractions at work), but I'd at least like to know if there's a way to get that list back on that specific page. Either that or I need to update my bookmark...

Forgive my ignorance but what is the difference between the homepage and the questions page (i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions)? The questions page has it. Can you just switch to using that instead?

Not sure what you meant by bookmark, but Stack Exchange homepage still has HNQ list.

The entire new homepage has been very poorly received. For a origin "like" experience, you're better off visiting the questions page.
